# How is Flutter compared with other technologies like React Native or NativeScript?

Tags: flutter

So how is it compared to React Native or NativeScript?

I know the differences but I was looking for an answer from someone with real experience usng Flutter.

- Does it worth to learn it? Why should I learn this instead of Java?
- How is the learning curve?
- Are there many apps using Flutter?
- NativeScript is quite handy for testing generating also a QR code for different devices to test direclty. How is testing using Flutter?
- I heard that update from an old version is not painful at all like it happened to me with Ionic from 1-2, 2-3 and 3-4. Is that true?

And the most important one for me:
- How often do you get stuck coding with Flutter and how difficult is to find documentation?

Comment: Use it man, it's really really good.

Comment: How much experience do you have using it? I don't mind learning new technologies but I find myself learning all the time and I need to refactor the same app many times so at the end I spend more time learning than coding. Don't know... I'll definetely have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:

> Does it worth to learn it? Why should I learn this instead of Java?

Dart (the programming language) and Flutter (the UI Framework) are targeting universal apps. Meaning your code will be compiled for both iOS and Android. You don't have to go for both platforms but you can. Java on the other hand is used for Android development only. There is no way you can deliver an iOS native App when programming Java. (At least no way that would be popular).

The best thing about Flutter I personally find is that it is the first hybrid technology that **really** works. Meaning the performance is stunning. The framework as such is absolutely powerful. Dart is awesome for reactive programming and all of that stuff. I am in the middle of a client project and I can say this is just a pleasure to work with Flutter.

I personally would even use Flutter when I have to target only one platform. At least for most of my projects.

> How is the learning curve?

Guess this also depends on your overall programming experience and if you have already written Apps in general. I did get nice results pretty quickly since there are so many tutorials already. For example on YouTube you can find a dedicated [Flutter Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw). In addition to that there are plenty of YouTubers that really explain everything in detail.

> NativeScript is quite handy for testing generating also a QR code for
>   different devices to test direclty. How is testing using Flutter?

Well you are able to read QR codes with flutter. There is a nice [Medium article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-flutter-qr-code-generator-scanner-and-sharing-app-703e73b228d3) about that.

> I heard that update from an old version is not painful at all like it
>   happened to me with Ionic from 1-2, 2-3 and 3-4. Is that true?

That is pretty much a general problem when using frameworks. Even a general problem in coding as such. We're in Flutter 1.x right now. Nobody really knows what will happen with Flutter 2.0. Also in addition to that you are pretty much generating native code for iOS and Android. Which means that you might run into native issues besides the one with Flutter. I am currently struggling with Android X which is a non-Flutter related problem. You just cannot be sure how things like that will turn out in the future.

> How often do you get stuck coding with Flutter and how difficult is to
>   find documentation?

This was also one of my questions when I started writing Flutter code. There are so many options like NativeScript and others. They often promise to be so damn easy and flexible but at the end of the day when you need that little bit more in a specialised UI you're stuck. Flutter did not let me down till today. Of course there will be moments which seem to be a dead end. But as far as I can tell the community especially here on StackOverflow knows the answer to almost everything.

Also there is a YouTuber channel called [Fluttery](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtWyVkPpb8An90SNDTNF0Pg) which kinda proves that Flutter is pretty much limitless in terms of UI. It opens your eyes that many things are possible. :)

Hope that helps a bit. At the end of the day you have to decide. Not others.

Comment: Wow mate, thanks for the answer.
I'll take this: "I personally would even use Flutter when I have to target only one platform". That sounds really good and also if you did not find any issue with Flutter yet that's also quite promising. I'm doing React Native right now and I got stuck several times just trying to create a normal routing between pages.
I also love CSS. How flexible is Flutter on this? I know I need to forget about DOM and html but tbh NativeScript was quite easy in this aspect to me

Comment: Of course you do not have regular CSS when using Flutter. But you will find many similarities to developing for the web. F.ex. you'll have rows and cols just like using Flexbox. Also padding, sizing and many others will be a no brainer as a web developer. I suggest getting your feet wet with flutter. Chances are you will not regret it. :)

Comment: And something I didn't ask about: how many offers are out there with Flutter? I understand there shouldn't be too many but how is it growing commercially speaking?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely yes, What I say, Flutter is like yeah for the developers of Hybrid and Native app developers.

Flutter is too good for the developers of the mobile application as he/she needs to code for the app for once and he can run that code on both IOS and Android platform.

Flutter uses Dart Language, which is originally developed by Google so it’s really good for the developers to learn and understand its concepts.

There are several applications developed using Flutter (Google Ads,Alibaba...)
More : https://itsallwidgets.com/

There are some features that make Flutter a best one among other hybrid app development frameworks.
Plugins 
Hot reload feature
Material design components support
Widget is everything
Themes support for IOS / Android
Reach set of libraries and so on.
There are many more features that make you love a flutter.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. How much experience do you have with it? What's the best and the worst thing about Flutter?